# Action of $S^1$ on itself

Tags: group-actions, vector-fields

I'm reading some lecture notes about equivariant cohomology.
It says that:

> Consider the action of the circle on itself by rotations. The circle $S^1$ is parametrized by the angle $\phi$. The action of $S^1$ on $S^1$ is generated by the vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$.

Please someone explain to me why is this action generated by that vector field.

Ps: the lecture notes I am reading are written in french, so please excuse me if my translation to the quote is bad !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this action as follows:
$G=SO(2)=\Big\{R(\phi)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\phantom{-}\cos\phi&\sin\phi\\-\sin\phi&\cos\phi\end{smallmatrix}\right),\ \phi\in[0,2\pi]\Big\}\cong S^1$, $M=S^1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,\ x^2+y^2=1\}$ and the action is by rotation:
$$\phi\cdot\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\ y\end{smallmatrix}\right):=R(\phi)\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\ y\end{smallmatrix}\right).$$
Equivalently, the vector field $\partial_{\phi}$ is $X=-y\partial_x+x\partial_y$ (in cartesian coordinates). The flow of $X$ acts on $S^1$ and it's of the form $$\exp tX=R(t)\ \text{rotation}.$$

Comment: Dear @Anonymous thank you for your answer!  I have two questions: 1) what does it mean to say that an action of a group on some object is generated by a Vector field (I have never come across  this notion  before except in this example) and 2) how to determine this vector field ?

Comment: Dear @asma 1) A 'complete' vector field $X$ generates an action of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ on the manifold via its flow $t.:=\exp tX(x)$.

Comment: 2) For the local diffeomorphism $\varphi(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, $\varphi_*\partial_\theta(x,y)=D_{(r,\theta)}\varphi(\partial_\theta)=-r\sin\theta\partial_x+r\cos\theta\partial_y$. Or simply the chain rule, for any function $f$ on the circle $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x)\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}$$

Comment: the chain rule, for any function f on the circle $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}=-y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

Comment: thank you for these explanations ! I'm sorry to bother you again by one more question: actually I still don't understand what does  is it mean in general to say that a vector field generates an action ( do we have in general general a lot of vector fields which generate the action of the group on a manifold or there is just one ?).  Could you suggest me a reference which speak about this notion  and give some examples ?

Comment: It doesn't bother me, I find it fun to answer questions. To a complete $X$ is associated a group action of $(\mathbb{R},+)$: $t\cdot x=\exp tX(x)$ because: $0\cdot x=id(x)=x$, $(t+s)\cdot x=\exp(t+s)X(x)=\exp tX\left(\exp sX(x)\right)=t\cdot (s\cdot x)$. Example: $M=\mathbb{R}^2$ $X=x\partial_x-y\partial_y$, the action is $t\cdot(x,y)=(e^tx,e^{- t}y)$. If $X_1,...,X_k$ are complete and commute two by two then they generate an action of the abelian group $(\mathbb{R}^k,+)$ by $(t_1,...,t_k)\cdot x=\exp t_1X\circ...\circ\exp t_kX(x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Anonymous for your comments, they were very helpful !

Answer (score 2):

The vector field $\frac\partial{\partial\phi}$ is rotation invariant, hence the action generated by it must be rotation invariant. The only ortation invariant actions on $S^1$ are - rotations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you elaborate more please. What does it mean in  for an action of a group to be generated by a vector field ? And I don't understand your last sentence: "The only rotation invariant action on $S^1$ are rotations ?